# Проблемы с удалением||downgrade requests в gentoo

Tags: python

обновили request до 1.1.0
стали терять куки.

хотим назад. 
pip install -I requests==0.14.2
выдает ошибку доступа

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests==0.14.2
```

Comment: замаскировать пакет и обновить мир помогло.

Comment: Не понял, при чем тут маскировка пакетов и pip? Пользуйтесь чем-нибудь одним либо portage, либо pip.

А еще советую использовать [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/).